# Issues with "background-position" in "background" shorthand property

Tags: css, background-image

I was attempting to use the `background` shorthand property to specify `background-size`, `background-repeat`, and `background-color`, but kept failing. I eventually realized that you have to set `background-position` if you set `background-size`, so I just set the property as `inherit / contain no-repeat #FF7000`, as to the best of my knowledge, the default `background-position` should be inherited from the parent (`body`, in this case), as I have not explicitly set `body`'s `background-position`. It still didn't work. However, this worked: `center / contain no-repeat #FF7000`. Why would setting it explicitly work and allowing it to inherit not work? My guess is that my understanding of how `inherit` works is mistaken, but I'm not sure.

Here's the entirety of the relevant code:

```
.side_img
{
    width: 150px;
    height: 300px;
    background: center / contain no-repeat #FF7000;
}

#left_side
{
    background-image: url("images/giraffe_painting.jpg");
}

#right_side
{
    background-image: url("images/giraffe_painting_reversed.jpg");
}
```

Also, in case this matters, the `id` selectors refer to `div`s.

Comment: They're separately specified for the individual divs. From what I read, `background-image` can be excluded from `background`. Am I wrong?

Comment: The code I posted works. I was wondering why I couldn't replace "center" with "inherit". If what you're saying is true, my code shouldn't work at all.

Comment: well It was about something else ... but you cannot inherit a part of a property I guess

Comment: check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background and you will see the formal syntax [the BIG blue box], you need to follow this syntax and inherit is not allowed

Comment: That's probably it. I used `inherit` as a subvalue when it can only be used as a full value.

Comment: by the way you can try `initial` it may work

Comment: Already tried it. It didn't.

Comment: so your goal is to avoid setting background-position in the shorthand?

Comment: That is my goal. Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) of the `background` property, `background-size` cannot be set alone and it should be used with `background-position`. Also `inherit` and `initial` aren't valid values for those properties.

[image]

Comment: Temani Afif I asked as question if this was wrong and you just marked it as a duplicate of this! that was not helpful at all! as I could write mine myself, but this was in bootstrap so would have been much more professional to say what is wrong and not point me to this. As I still don't know what exactly is wrong with it. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60930928/css-background-long-syntax-issue