# Error: CSS: background: / is an incorrect operator

Tags: css, background, w3c-validation

I have the following HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <title>test</title>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div style="height:100%;background: url('https://apprecs.org/ios/images/app-icons/256/90/1097333136.jpg') 100% 0 no-repeat / 4%;">
      <p>
      bob
      Is
      The 
      best!

      </p>

    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

The image displays well but when I go to the [HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) I get an error:

> Error: CSS: background: / is an incorrect operator.

If I remove that `/` then the image doesn't appear. What is the correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we refer to the [formal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background#Formal_syntax):

[image]

The `/` is the separation between `background-position` and `background-size` (this one being optional) so the correct syntax is:

```
 background: url(...) 100% 0/4% no-repeat;
```

Where `background-position:100% 0` and `background-size:4%`

Note that `background-size` should always be specified with `background-position` when using shorthand syntax. You cannot specify the size without position but you can specify position without size:

```
 background: url(...) 100% 0 no-repeat;
```

---

Relatad question: [Issues with "background-position" in "background" shorthand property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50498602/8620333)