# CSS variables and SASS functions

Tags: css, sass, css-variables

We know the advantages of using CSS4 variables but what if we need to get these values from a SASS function like so?:

```
:root {
    --gap-l: toRem(10);
}
```

`toRem` is a Sass function that I call to get the sizes dynamically:

```
$fontSize: 16;
@function toRem($val) {
    @return $val / $fontSize * 1.6 + 0rem;
}
```

This won't fail but won't work either. To have this working we can just have the value directly on `--gap-l` or keep using SASS vars.

If I try something like `--gap-l: #{toRem(10)};`

The error I encounter is that it doesn't call the SASS function:

[image]

Comment: There is nothing called "CSS4 variables", that's why I edited the question to make it "CSS variables" which is the correct term.

Comment: I always understood that was CSS4 variables: https://codepen.io/jakealbaugh/post/css4-variables-and-sass or https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/14801

Comment: those links are using wrong temrs. you will find noting about CSS4 variables in any official specification. Even CSS4 as term doesn't exist, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54055521/8620333

Comment: Ok, so it might be a misunderstanding about these terms on the internet then. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `--gap-l: #{toRem(10)};`, the `#{}` syntax is called [interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation). In the experience of heading bugs myself, when you want to use a SASS expression's raw value along with normal CSS, if you can't use the concise syntax like just `toRem(10)`, try adding interpolation to see if it works.
Another example:

```
$padding: 5px;
.element {
  width: calc(100% - $padding); // will not work, it must be:
  width: calc(100% - #{$padding});
}
```

Here is the code with the updated question: https://jsfiddle.net/bcw763en/.
Notice that if you put `:root` above the `@function`, it'll not work.

Comment: @Dani Did you put `:root` above or below the function?

Comment: @Dani try the jsfiddle snippet I gave above. You might put `:root` at the top of the file, and `@function` below it so it's not recognized.

Comment: that was the error! The function was below the css var and apparently with these vars this doesn't work like that

Comment: happy it helped

Answer (score 3):

You can definitely do that: what you're missing is simply using string interpolation, i.e.:

```
:root {
  --gap-l: #{toRem(10)};
}
```

The reason is highlighted in their "breaking changes" documentation with regards to [CSS variables](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/css-vars):

> To provide maximum compatibility with plain CSS, more recent versions of Sass require SassScript expressions in custom property values to be written within [interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation). Interpolation will also work for older Sass versions, and so is recommended for all stylesheets.

Comment: `--gap-l` is a css4 var which contains a value it's being used like `padding: var(--gap-l);`

Comment: @Dani Of course: and I don't see why my answer would be different.

Comment: Thanks! Got the error, I had to move as well the function before this css4 var

Comment: @TemaniAfif Sorry, I was in a bad mood and now I'm trying to delete the comment but can't find it. Thank you if you did.