# CSS hover transition, width from the center

Tags: html, css, width, transition

I was wondering how I would make an object wider from the center, instead of from the left.
Here is my HTML:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <a href='#'>Hover</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is my CSS:

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-color:#262626;
}
a{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  padding:10px 25px;
  border:2px solid white;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
  font-family:verdana;
  font-size:27px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  letter-spacing:4px;
  transform:1s;
}
a::before{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:0%;
  top:0;
  left:50%;
  z-index:-1;
  background-image:linear-gradient(45deg, #eea949,#ff3984);
  transition:.5s;
}
a:hover::before{
  width:100%;
}
```

instead of widening from the center on hover, it widens from the left. I have tried adding transform: translate(-50%, 0); to the a:hover::before in the css, it kind of worked, but it made it a little wobbly (I don't know how to explain it). Can someone help with this?

Comment: Are you looking for the before element to grow and span the whole link, or what do you mean widen from the left? Otherwise, you can change it's left property from 50% to 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with only background:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #262626;
}

a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 10px 25px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 27px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #eea949, #ff3984) center/0% 100% no-repeat;
}

a:hover {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href='#'>Hover</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! What exactly does center/0% 100% do? is there somewhere that explains it more in detail?

Comment: @HoneyPoop it's a shorthand to mean `position/size` so I place the gradient in the center with a size width=0% and height=100% then on hover I update only the size

Comment: @HoneyPoop check this for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54055521/8620333

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it. I added a `::after` to the element, rotated the gradient, and made the `::after` go left `50%`, while the `::before` went right `50%`. Like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #262626;
}

a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 10px 25px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 27px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  transform: 1s;
}

a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0%;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #eea949, #ff3984);
  transition: .5s;
}

a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0%;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #ff3984, #eea949);
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: .5s;
}

a:hover::before {
  width: 50%;
}

a:hover::after {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <a href='#'>Hover</a>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope this helps. If you want to see a JSFiddle, click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/th7ue1mn/).

Answer (score 0):

Add these styles to the body element to center the link. Then remove the `position: absolute; top: 0 and left:0;` from the link (they would be redundant with flex) and add this style to make it parent.

```
body{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
} 
a{ 
    position: relative
    transition: all .1s;
}
```

and then add `transform: translateX(-50%);` on the a:hover::before{} as you wanted.
This format I found to not have a wobble.