# Is there a way to make a CSS gradient choppy?

Tags: css, gradient, linear-gradients

See below for an example of what I want to achieve.
[image: choppy and smooth gradient]

I can see the difference between the two, but if you can't, here's another image.

[image: smooth and choppy gradient 2]

Comment: This is beyond my ken but you might be able to do it with SVG filters? https://codepen.io/AmeliaBR/pen/ZYGYOQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by applying another gradient on a top of it:

```css
html {
   height:100%;
   background:
     linear-gradient(transparent,rgba(0,0,0,0.03)) 0 0/100% 20px,
     linear-gradient(#1ec5a6,#fff);
}
```

Comment: What does the `0 0/100% 20px` part of the code do? I can't find that syntax on W3Schools, Mozilla Developer Network and CSS Tricks.

Comment: @desbest it's `background-position/background-size` : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54055521/8620333

Comment: But there are 4 numbers instead of 2.  And why are there 2 numbers for background size?

Comment: @desbest `X Y/width height`