# "cover" property bugging the background

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am having a problem with covering the background in CSS.

Before:

```css
.main-bg {
  background: no-repeat url("../../images/main_bg.jpeg");
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
}
```

[Image Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMyge.png)

After:

```css
.main-bg {
  background: no-repeat url("../../images/main_bg.jpeg") cover;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
}
```

[Image After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTI2w.png)

Anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Try `background: url("../../images/main_bg.jpeg"); background-size: cover;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have `cover` alone in the background property. You are obliged to define the position as well:

```
background: no-repeat url("../../images/main_bg.jpeg") center/cover;
```

Or add `background-size: cover`

Related: [Error: CSS: background: / is an incorrect operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54055445/8620333)