# Why the center/cover background property?

Tags: css, responsive-design, background-image

For example in the property declaration below there is already a `center` value. Why add `center/cover` and not just `cover` to the `background` property?

`background: url('../img/bg.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;`

Comment: `center center/cover` is equivalent to `center/cover` ... more precisely it's `center center` = `center`

Comment: Is ```center cover``` also equivalent to ```center/cover```?

Comment: no, the `/` is the sepration between background-position and background-size

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50498799/8620333

Comment: and at the end of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734530/8620333 you will find a list of equivalent value

Comment: Yes it does. Just upvoted your other answers. Thanks!