# Can a linear gradient be a different size than its container?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

In this very simple example, is it possible in CSS to:

1. Have the black lines not be as wide as the gray area?
2. Use a repeating linear gradient rather than repeat each black/transparent section?
3. Have the black lines centered in the height of the gray area without knowing in advance how tall the gray area is?

I can make a second more narrow div to hold the black lines as a repeating linear gradient and position it in the center of the gray div; but wondered if it is possible with one div.

I see that they can make complex plaid designs with gradients and all kinds of intricate things; but I'm not at all all artistic and a few perpendicular lines is a challenge.

Thanks for any direction you may be able to provide.

```css
:root { --start: 8.0rem; }
html { font-size: 62.5% }
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20.0rem;
  background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
  background-image: linear-gradient( to bottom,
     transparent var(--start),
     black var(--start), black calc(var(--start) + 0.1rem),
     transparent calc(var(--start) + 0.1rem), transparent calc(var(--start) + 0.3rem),
     black calc(var(--start) + 0.3rem), black calc(var(--start) + 0.4rem),
     transparent calc(var(--start) + 0.4rem), transparent calc(var(--start) + 0.6rem),
     black calc(var(--start) + 0.6rem), black calc(var(--start) + 0.7rem),
     transparent calc(var(--start) + 0.7rem), transparent calc(var(--start) + 0.9rem),
     black calc(var(--start) + 0.9rem), black calc(var(--start) + 1.0rem),
     transparent calc(var(--start) + 1.0rem), transparent calc(var(--start) + 1.2rem),
     black calc(var(--start) + 1.2rem), black calc(var(--start) + 1.3rem),
     transparent calc(var(--start) + 1.3rem), transparent calc(var(--start) + 1.5rem),
     black calc(var(--start) + 1.5rem), black calc(var(--start) + 1.6rem),
     transparent calc(var(--start) + 1.6rem), transparent
   );
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a size and position for a gradient

```css
:root { --start: 8.0rem; }
html { font-size: 62.5% }
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20.0rem;
  background: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(black 0 0.1rem,#0000 0 0.3rem)
    center/  /* position */
    60% 1.6rem /* size (width height) */
    no-repeat /* don't repeat */
    rgb(200,200,200); /* background color */
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Related:

[Error: CSS: background: / is an incorrect operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54055445/8620333)

[Issues with "background-position" in "background" shorthand property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50498602/8620333)

Comment: Thank you. So simple when you know what you're doing. I fogot that `background` was the properrty and got focused on just the one piece of it. I better take a look at my CSS book again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Your requirements can be met by combining several CSS features:

- Pseudo-elements (generated content) where you will place your background gradient so that it is not full width
- CSS grid (or flex box) to horizontally and vertically the pseudo-element
- Using `repeating-linear-gradient()` once you know the pattern you want
- Setting an explicit height to control how many "bands" you want to see

Based on your demo, I figured out want 11 bands of alternating black and transparent bands, with black being 0.1rem tall and transparent being 0.2rem tall. That will give you a total height of 1.6rem, which you will use to set the explicit height of the pseudo-element.

For the width part it's not clear what your requirements are, so let's say you want the gradient to only be half the width of the parent element.

See proof-of-concept below:

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%
}

#demo {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20.0rem;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

#demo::before {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 1.6rem;
    content: '';
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      black,
      black 0.1rem,
      transparent 0.1rem,
      transparent 0.3rem
    );
  }
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a good technique to know. I selected the other answer because it is more concise and uses `background` fully, which I stupidly (because I've used it before) never even considered. I used it maybe two years ago for a background picture on the full screen and haven't  used it since. Thanks again.